# Multiple buttons on one form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have searched on stackoverflow and google and have found many articles on the subject but I still can't seem to know what I am doing wrong! I really feeling desperate. E.g.
[How to handle two submit buttons on MVC view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616154/how-to-handle-two-submit-buttons-on-mvc-view)

I'm just trying to have three buttons in my view. I do hit the action in the controller, however, the string comparison does not work. For some reason, I cannot hit my breakpoints.

Here's my code:
View:

```
@using RequestDB7mvc.Models
@model MainViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Main";
}
<div class="form-group">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search4", "Requests", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="command" />
    <input type="submit" value="Done" name="command" />
    <input type="submit" value="Cancel" name="command" />
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search4(MainViewModel model, string command)
{
    if (command.Equals("Save"))
    {
        // Call action here...
        string f = "break";
    }
    else if (command.Equals("Done"))
    {
        // Call another action here...
        string f = "break";
    }
    else if (command.Equals("Cancel"))
    {
        // Call another action here...
        string f = "break";
    }

    ViewBag.Msg = "Details saved successfully.";
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Did you try and debug as to what you are getting in the command parameters in the action. If you cannot hit breakpoint, try writing to trace and verify

Comment: I did try. And I see the command value, e.g."Cancel". However, it does not jump into the if statement :-(

Comment: try command.Equals("Cancel", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)

Comment: Thank you. I tried. Didn't work. Can I attach a picture here? Here is the debugger screenshot: http://imgur.com/OKmSJTF

Comment: @Nearshore how do you send MainViewModel model, string command values in your request. I couldnt see any form input data in question?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `command` into your Model.

```
public class MainViewModel
{

    ...

    public string command { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Then in your controller, remove the command parameter and handle from the model:

```
public ActionResult Search4(MainViewModel model)
{
    if (model.command.Equals("Save"))
    {
        // Call action here...
        string f = "break";
    }
    else if (model.command.Equals("Done"))
    {
        // Call another action here...
        string f = "break";
    }
    else if (model.command.Equals("Cancel"))
    {
        // Call another action here...
        string f = "break";
    }

    ViewBag.Msg = "Details saved successfully.";
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ashley. I cannot explain it to myself, but it still not works! It is unbelievable.